# Having "key is a directory name" exception

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
S3DirectoryInfo dir= new S3DirectoryInfo(client, "bucketname", "sampledir/sample");
test.Create();
var files = dir.GetFiles();
```

so using `dir.GetFiles()`, i can't get the files inside the directory.
how can i solve this????

Comment: Do you get any error while doing the above operation?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "key is  a directory name" @error2007s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of above code use this below code it will work. The change is trailing slash.

```
S3DirectoryInfo dir= new S3DirectoryInfo(client, "bucketname","sampledir\sample");
    test.Create();
    var files = dir.GetFiles();
```